# Defining destination NAT in fargate container

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

How can I define a destination nat in a fargate container? If I was creating containers under EC2 instances I would use iptables and create a dnat entry. Can that be done in a fargate container and if so, how?

I have not been able to figure out how to define iptables in a fargate container yet. I cannot use a Net Gateway because I am not trying to do a NAT to an internal address, but I need to define a destination NAT.

Comment: Well, you can't do the trick with Fargate. You simply do not controll the underlying resources. Awsvpc mode only. From networking perspective, a Fargate container is like a EC2 Instances. Can you set a dNat rule in a Subnet level for an Instance?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be done. I've tried before and didn't find any feature available to do that.

What I ended up doing was adding a [Route53 private hosted zone](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/hosted-zones-private.html) to the VPC for the custom DNS resolution within the VPC.

Comment: That would work, but the networking that needs to be done is all via IP address. Trying to interface with an old Centera protocol that allows me to open using a DNS name, but then gets a redirect using a IP address and cannot intercept the redirect to provide a DNS name for the redirect. The only way I have been able to do this through a DNAT and under EC2 this would be simple.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a NLB, set up a listener on a port you need, attach a target groupt to the listener. Optionally, put a Global Accelerator with single static IP in front of the NLB and you will get exactly the same networking as you want.

Comment: Will this work for UDP traffic or only TCP? The Centera protocol requires TCP and UDP. It also requires 6 IPs to be mapped.   I have to map IP x.x.x.x to y.y.y.y outbound for both UDP and TCP on a single network port. i have to do this with 6 IPs. The x.x.x.x is not part of my subnet or the subnet that fargate is sitting in. With iptables DNAT, I can do the conversion of x.x.x.x to y.y.y.y within the TCP stack

Comment: UDP and TCP would work on NLB.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, what about a [NAT instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html). Once installed you get a full controll on the networning, TCP and UDP, DNAT and SNAT, literally any scenario is possible now. You are able to forward trafic to fargate.